# Jekyll - Recommended way of importing files

Tags: css, jekyll, microsoft-edge, css-import

In my recent efforts to understand, maintain & add features to an existing website, built with Jekyll, I have posted a few questions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041831/jekyll-couldnt-find-file-in-index-html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061010/edge17-sec7136-the-origin-failed-an-integrity-check-for-a-resource)).

I have added a [js slider plugin](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) on the home page. The CSS file that came with the slider was added to the folder: '/assets/'

And then imported in the '_assets/css/app.scss' `sass` file: `@import "flexslider.css`;

Now everything is running fine in browsers, including latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera & Edge upto version 16. Edge 17 (latest) is flagging up an error with a message:

`SEC7136: The origin 'http://staging.whatever.com' failed an integrity check for a style resource 'http://staging.whatever.com/assets/flexslider.css'`

I do not understand why `Edge 17` would be the only one flagging this & what the integrity check is all about, it appears to be related to some sort of security check fail.

My main question is, is the above method of appending a CSS file in a jekyll project correct? Is there a recommended way of importing css files within project?

Comment: please see this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51098088/434697

Comment: This may also help with importing `.css` into `.scss`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file